# Updating Button Text with value when service returns data and updates a model object

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await

Initially, we just show the view (popup window) with the value which came from service and this value can change before user actually accepts it. This value comes only once and in order to request the new value we need to call one analytics service again. We just get the updates that the status of the stock has changed.
I have a ViewModel with property AcceptButtonValue which is binded to the views button. Also, there is a model object say Stock whose prices keep ticking and I wanted to show the latest price on the button before user accept the price.

I trigger AcceptButtonValue property value change on Stock's status property change and call below method on the getter of the property. But as you can see in code example I cannot call await on UpdateAcceptButtonValue and I read that calling async without await is bad practice.
Please advise how to handle this scenario in a more appropriate manner.

```
stock.PropertyChanged = (s,e) => 
{
  switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case "Status":
            RaisPropertyChange("AcceptButtonValue");
            break;
    }  
}

AcceptButtonValue
{
  get
   {
      UpdateAcceptButtonValue(stock)
      return stock.InitialPrice;
   }
}

private async Task UpdateAcceptButtonValue(Stock stock)
{
  var result = await _pricingService.GetLatestPrice(stock.Id);
  AcceptButtonValue = string.Format("$(0)",result);
}
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx) blog post and espacial the `NotifyTaskCompletion` class

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at the link @Ackdari

Comment: Hi @Ackdari I read the link and it was really useful. But I tried one more thing.var result = Task.Run(()=>_pricingService.GetLatestPrice).GetAwaiter().GetResult() and it was working.Do you see any issue with the approach?

Comment: glap to here that. It is never a good idea to not await a `Task` if it is possible, because every call to `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` or `Result` has the potential to cause deadlocks.

Comment: Understood..I am doing some refactoring as you suggested and will try to do it in property so that I can remove potential deadlock situations